# why full screen not working when i embedding bunny.net videos in react native app

Tags: react-native, video, expo

```
<WebView source={{ uri: 'https://iframe.mediadelivery.net/play/221837/036c6c24-048b-4a80-931b-2393766561c9' }} />
```

using above code I embedding bunny.net videos in react native app when I run the application all function are working but full screen button not working in the video player.

how can I fix that??

Comment: add allowsFullscreenVideo={true}